# How to clear response from fetch call in useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect, react-typescript

I have a Search app, where a user enters some text, and on clicking a button, I trigger an effect to fetch data from an API and store it in results variable. I then use this results variable to render the Data in a table.

```
const [results, setResults] = useState<unknown[] | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(getEndpoint(), requestOptions).then((response) =>
        response.json().then((data) => {
            setResults(data); // data is an array of objects that returns some values
    })}, [userSearchValue]); // userSearchValue is the user input in the search field, when it 
                                changes and user clicks search, the effect runs again
```

When a user resets the input field and makes another search request, what is the best way to clear the results data every time a call is made?

I'm brand new to hooks, so any help is truly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Why are you doing this in a `useEffect` and not an `onChange` event in the `input` element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set onChange or onBlur Event everytime user change the Search Result

```
<TextInput>
   value={value}
   onBlur={handleSearchResult}
   onChange={handleSearchResult}
</TextInput>
```

This will call the handleSearchResult function everytime user search for particular data

```
handleSearchResult = (event) => {
   let {name , value} = event.target;
   // your logic here for reset value and set useEffect flag value to reload
}
```